# Highstocks chart: Show one week data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highstocks to draw a chart. I want to display data of 1 week and I have a list of dates.
This chart shows the price per day with a line chart and quantity per day with a column chart. Data is coming from database.

Required feature:
1. user can change the timeframe easily.
2. display data of 1 week

So, please help me how can I achieve this?

Here what I have tried:

```
         Highcharts.stockChart(id,{
                chart: {
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Product Price-Quantity Chart'
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 2,
                    allButtonsEnabled: true,
                    inputEnabled: true,
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'week',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1w'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }          
                },

                xAxis: [{
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {                 
                        day: '%Y-%m-%d'          

                     },                         
              }],

                yAxis: [{
                    title: 'Price',
                    height: '50%',
                    offset: 0,
                    tickInterval: 10,
                    lineWidth:2                     
                },{                 
                    title: 'Quantity',
                    top: '50%',
                    height: '50%',
                    offset: 0,
                    tickInterval: 100,
                    lineWidth:2
                } ],        

                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    name: 'Price',
                    data: price,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 3, 1),
                    pointEnd: Date.UTC(2020, 3 , 30),
                    pointInterval:  2*24 * 3600 * 1000,
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: "Price {point.y: .2f}"
                    }                     
                } ,{                        
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'quantity',
                    data: quantity,
                    yAxis: 1,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 3, 1),
                    pointEnd: Date.UTC(2020, 3 , 30),
                    pointInterval: 2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000                           
                }]
            });
```

Output: [image]

Comment: It seems that your options work fine, but you need to apply more data (bigger data range) to make buttons works properly. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qxpfw83d/

Comment: Suppose I have a date = ['07-04-2020', '27-04-2020', '29-04-2020','30-04-2020'], price = [8.00,30.00,20.00,15.00] and quantity = [100,500,400,600]. Now if I want to show 1 week data  then i have price for three days i.e '27-04-2020', '29-04-2020','30-04-2020'. and for this pointInterval: 24*3600*1000 then it is showing the price on  '27-04-2020', '28-04-2020' and '29-04-2020'. But there is no data for 28-04-2020. I want that data should show according to date.

Comment: I have updated your JS fiddle.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel if a user change the timeframe and select next week of the same month. So, how do Highstocks charts links which data is for which date?

Comment: there is a reproduction of your requirements. Take a look at how the data structure should look like. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dx7spgv4/ Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for clearing my doubt. I have one more query that how can a user change the timeframe?

Comment: Do you want to use another way than using the rangeSelector? I am not sure if I understood you well... https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/range-selector

Comment: I have set "inputEnabled: true" still when I am changing the dates manually, it is not happening.

Comment: In the demo which I shared above, change the "from" label to 2020-04-20 and click enter. On my device, everything works as expected. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: but in my device, it's not working

Comment: That's how it looks like on my side: https://imgur.com/a/Teuyn06. May I see your attempt?

Comment: if data points are small in length means if data series length is minimum ex. 3 then it is not working

Comment: `priceData=[[27-04-2020, 30.00],[29-04-2020,20.00],[01-05-2020, 18.00]]; quantityData = [[27-04-2020, 600],[29-04-2020,400],[01-05-2020, 600]];`

Comment: Could you reproduce it in the demo?

Comment: It's working with a sufficient amount of data points

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the issue which you are struggling to. Are you able to reproduce it on the online editor with description?